# Combine two groups of data in one column from two different tables

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently doing a patient record system for a dental clinic. I need to display all treatments done to the patient, but I have two tables for treatment. Is there a way to combine columns from the two different tables?

Both of the tables have appointmentid, datecreated, procedure. I tried using coalesce function, but when the appointmentid is present in both tables, only the first one displays.

```php
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE patient_number = '".$_GET['patient_number']."'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) { 

       $sql1 = "SELECT appointment.id, coalesce(alltreatment.datecreated, toothtreatment.datecreated) AS col0 , 
             coalesce(alltreatment.appointmentid, toothtreatment.appointmentid) AS col1, 
             coalesce(alltreatment.procedures, toothtreatment.procedures) AS col3, 
             coalesce(alltreatment.amount, toothtreatment.amount) AS col4
            FROM appointment LEFT JOIN alltreatment ON appointment.id = alltreatment.appointmentid                                               
            LEFT JOIN toothtreatment ON appointment.id = toothtreatment.appointmentid                                            
           WHERE appointment.id = '".$row3['id']."' ORDER BY col1 DESC";

            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {  
                          echo '
                       <tr>  

                            <td>'.$row1['col1'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row1['col0'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row1['col3'].'</td>

                       </tr>  
            ';
            }
    }
```

Expected result:

```
1|2004-12-05|Cleaning (from treatment1)
1|2004-12-05|Tooth Extraction (from treatment2)
```

Comment: Think about changing that schema and only have one table for the treatments.

Comment: My professor advised me to have different tables from treatment which include tooth only like extraction and the other is the whole mouth like cleaning, whitening

Comment: Then I hope it's not a professor lecturing database systems or basically anything on computer science but maybe dentistry or whatever...

Comment: You are selecting 4 columns, whereas you expected result has 6 columns. Is this intended?

Comment: @clinique did the answer below work for you? If so would you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4dd42/5

```
create table appointment (id int)
create table alltreatment (id int, appointmentid int, procedures varchar(50), amount int, datecreated datetime)
create table toothtreatment (id int, appointmentid int, procedures varchar(50), amount int, datecreated datetime)

insert into appointment (id) values (1)
insert into alltreatment (id, appointmentid, procedures, amount, datecreated) values (10, 1, 'Cleaning', 100, '20041205')
insert into toothtreatment (id, appointmentid, procedures, amount, datecreated) values (20, 1, 'Tooth Extraction', 150, '20041205')

SELECT
    appointment.id, 
    alltreatment.datecreated,
    alltreatment.procedures,
    alltreatment.amount
FROM appointment
INNER JOIN alltreatment ON appointment.id = alltreatment.appointmentid 
WHERE appointment.id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    appointment.id, 
    toothtreatment.datecreated,
    toothtreatment.procedures,
    toothtreatment.amount
FROM appointment
INNER JOIN toothtreatment ON appointment.id = toothtreatment.appointmentid 
WHERE appointment.id = 1
ORDER BY appointment.id DESC
```

It gives the following output:

```
id  datecreated             procedures          amount
1   2004-12-05T00:00:00Z    Cleaning            100
1   2004-12-05T00:00:00Z    Tooth Extraction    150
```

Alternatively, the following query gives the same results:

```
SELECT
    appointment.id, 
    t.datecreated,
    t.procedures,
    t.amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        appointmentid, 
        datecreated,
        procedures,
        amount
    FROM alltreatment
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        appointmentid, 
        datecreated,
        procedures,
        amount
    FROM toothtreatment 
) t
INNER JOIN appointment ON appointment.id = t.appointmentid 
WHERE appointment.id = 1
ORDER BY appointment.id DESC
```